# htaccess rule to redirect all requests to directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My file structure is like so:

```
app
  /some
  /private
  /app
  /directories
public
  /assets
    /images
    /js
    /css
  index.php (app entry point)
  robots.txt
```

If someone tries to access anything (existing or not) in `/app/*` the request will be rerouted to `/public/index.php`.

If someone tries to access any *existing file in the `/public` directory, they can.

Everything else all gets routed to `/public/index.php`.

Here's what I have:

```
# If not an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

# Allow access to the public directory
RewriteRule ^(public)($|/) - [L]

# Redirect everything to this file
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteBase /
```

This is working great for me, but what I need to do is if a file exists in the `public` directory, I would like to be able to access it like so:

```
site.com/robots.txt
site.com/images/image.jpg
```

whereas now, I must use:

```
site.com/public/robots.txt
site.com/public/images/image.jpg
```

How can I modify these rules so that any existing files within the `public` directory can still be accessed without using `/public` in the path/URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If file exists in public directory then rewrite to public/...
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ public/$1 [L]

# Redirect everything to this file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```